# Selecting elements with jQuery and putting in array to amend css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a layout where I need each child div in two columns to have a minimum height equivalent to the height of the window. To do this, I use:

```
$('.element').css("min-height",$(window).height());
```

This works for my purposes, however I wish to apply this to a number of elements, as aforementioned.

I used an array to attempt to achieve this:

```
var length = [$('.first'), $('.second'), $('.third'), $('.fourth'), $('.one'), $('.two'), $('.three'), $('.four')];
length.css("min-height",$(window).height());
```

As I am only new at javascript, I am unsure if it is even possible to select elements in this manner. Any help would be appreciated. 

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jessjohnson331/ffm6h1v0/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When supplying multiple selectors, separate them by a comma:

```
$('.first, .second, .third, .fourth, .one, .two, .three, .four').css("min-height", $(window).height());
```

However the above code completely misses the point of classes; you should put a single class on all the above elements and use one selector only - exactly as your first example does.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of supplying multiple selectors, you could as well add a new class to all elements that need to be modified.

For example, add `class="adjust-min-height"` and then use

```
$('.adjust-min-height').css("min-height", $(window).height());
```

**edit:**

If you want to use an array similar to what you asked for in your question, you could do this:

```
var elements = ['.first', '.second', '#maybe-an-id', '.third'];
var selector = elements.join(', ');
$(selector).css('min-height', $(window).height());
```

You can of course put the `.join(', ')` after the array, I just split it up for clarity.